# C++ range for (how many punctuation in letters)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, range, punctuation

Question 1 :

```
#include <iosteam> 
#include <string>
using namespace std ; 
int main()
{
    string s("hello world!!!")
    decltype(s.size()) punct_cnt = 0 ; 
    for(auto c: s ) //I can't run this line in my C++ !
    if(ispunct(c))
        ++punct_cnt ;
    cout << punc_cnt << endl ;  
}
```

I don't know why I can't run "for(auto c : s )" , please help !

Qusetion 2 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;  
int main ()
{
    const string hexdigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    cout <<"Enter a series of number between 0 and 15" << "separated by spaces.hit ENTER when           finished" <<endl; 
    string result ;
    string::size_type n ;
    while (cin >> n )
        if ( n < hexdigits.size())
   result += hexdigits[n];
    cout <<"Your hex number is :" << result << endl; 
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0 ;
}
```

This code supposed to be success ,but when I input "1 2 3 4 5 6 " ,the outcome is just a newline ,I don't know what's wrong .`

Comment: can you elaborate on *"I can't run this line in my C++ !"* ?

Comment: Never ask two questions at the same time. These are two separate problems and should not be in one thread. My guess for the first question is that either your compiler does not support c++11 or you did not specify the appropriate compiler flags(e.g. --std=c++11)

Comment: If you're running with g++, don't forget to compile with the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: C++ tell me that it cant's deduce auto c , and can't use the new for loop.

Comment: It's compiler that tells you so, which one is it?

Comment: My compiler is visual c++ 2010 express

Comment: @larry VS2010 has poor support for the current c++11 language features. Get a newer version.

Comment: @larry VS2010 has its own non-standard *range based for loop* which is `for each (auto c in s)`, but you should instead get a C++11 compiler (at least VS2013) rather than rely on non-standard extensions

Answer (score 1):

For question 1:

- is it `#include <iosteam>` or `#include <iostream>`?
- make sure each complete statement ends with a semicolon
- you must mean `cout << punct_cnt << endl;` at the end there

Those are the bugs as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 2:**

Enter does not break the while loop it's just like the space.

To break the while loop you need to enter EOF. which is ctrl + z or ctrl + c depend on your OS.

Comment: There is nothing called empty input. Enter will do nothing. Go test it yourself. You need to enter EOF